# Javascript: How to emulate browser-cookie implementation?

Tags: javascript, cookies, node.js

I'm trying to a create a fully functional web proxy using node.js which essentially downloads the webpage and displays it to the client. I'm having a problem implementing cookies though as it's harder than I thought since they have so many rules.

Are there any libraries that have been already made to emulate how a browser handles cookies?

Comment: If it is a proxy, wouldn't you just pass cookie headers through transparently?

Comment: I hope you are doing this as purely a learning experiment (which is good to do) as there are already a ton of these production-hardend proxies build in Node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request), it already handles storing the cookies for consecutive requests in a cookie jar.

Or if you don't want to reinvent the wheel use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) from Nodejitsu for a full blown proxy.

Answer (score 1):

You should really have a look at Tobi's implementation of cookie, here are some useful links:

Cookie and cookie jar:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi/blob/master/lib/cookie/index.js
https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi/blob/master/lib/cookie/jar.js

Tests for cookie and cookie jar:
https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi/blob/master/test/cookie.test.js
https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi/blob/master/test/cookie.jar.test.js

Last but not least, look at the browser file, to see how they are implemented on requests: (look for every occurence of the word "cookie" in that file)
https://github.com/LearnBoost/tobi/blob/master/lib/browser.js